# drawing a background element

Tags: java, android, view, android-canvas

Current problem is that I am running into framerate issues on my simple android game due to me having to drawing a background for the view every time onDraw() is called. I am currently having to draw around 800 bitmaps on each time invalidate() is called, each of which is an element to a map. I am using a for loop to draw each of the bitmaps.

I was wondering if there was a more efficient method of drawing the bitmaps so that the background could only be drawn once and the player sprite is updated.

I currently tried to only draw the back ground once but the canvas will just overwrite the background leaving the view with a blank canvas and the character sprite.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use View.invalidate method with the dirty Rectangle as input

```
public void invalidate (Rect dirty)
```

For more info refer API reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate(android.graphics.Rect)